# Ubuntu Server 18.04 installation on Acer TC-1760 Series: "Block probing did not discover any disks."

Tags: 18.04, acer

I purchased this desktop PC and intend to install Ubuntu onto it (no Windows).  However, when installing Ubuntu from USB I get the following message: “Block probing did not discover any disks. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible.”.

Are there some common causes of this error that I can have a look for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good place to start is more info. Did this computer come with an OS installed on it? Did you follow a tutorial when making the Live Media? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: :-) Yes it came with Windows 11 installed on it.  The Live Media was built based on a tutorial and has been used before.  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question and add this important info. When installing did you tell Ubuntu to use the whole drive? Please review this info and make sure you have a good install. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

In order to make my SSD visible to the Ubuntu installation process I had to disable the VMD Controller, which resulted in it defaulting to AHCI.  It did not appear that any of the previous disk partitions were recognized, but I had intended to re-format anyway.

References:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?s=9cb36fa06e7250ba4251927cda0caf57&p=6355366#post6355366

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/650730/ubuntu-installer-cannot-find-hard-disk

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/641896/how-do-i-switch-to-ahci-mode-in-bios-acer-aspire-a514-54-5842/p2

https://www.linux.org/threads/ssd-playing-hide-and-seek.31926/